# Как вывести из json массива, нужные объекты?

Tags: html, jquery, json, select

Есть такой код:

```
window.onload = function() {
function Init() {
    // Setup HTML5 on start
    document.cookie = "playerHtml=true";
}

var xhrs = new XMLHttpRequest();
new autoComplete({
    selector: 'input[name=search-text]',
    minChars: 3,
    source: function(term, suggest) {
        xhrs.open('GET', '/autocomplete.php?name=' + term, false);
        xhrs.onload = function() {
            var suggestions = [];
            if (xhrs.status != 200 || xhrs.responseText.length == "") {
                return
            }
            result = JSON.parse(xhrs.responseText)
            for (i=0; i<result.suggestions.valu.length; i++) {
                if (/sil\-/i.test(result.data[i]) == false) {
                    continue;
                }
                suggestions.push({
                    'title': result.suggestions.valu[i],
                    'link': result.data[i],
                    'id': result.id[i],
                });
            }
            suggest(suggestions)
        }
        xhrs.send(null);
        alert( xhrs.send(null) );
    },
    renderItem: function (item, search) {
        if (item.link.length == 0) {
            return '<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-link="/">'+item.title+''+item.id+'</div>';
        }
        return '<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-link="/?title='+item.title+''+item.id+'"><a href="?title='+item.title+''+item.id+'">'+item.title+'</a></div>';
    },      
    onSelect: function(e, term, item) {
        link = item.getAttribute('data-link');
        if (link != "/") {
            location = link;
        }
    }
    });


echo(suggestions);
Init();
```

};

Который из JSON вида:

```
{"query":"a","suggestions":{"valu":["TitleOneRu \/ TitleOneEn","TitleTwoRu \/ TitleTwoEn"],"data":["sil-TitleOne.html","sil-TitleTwo.html"],"id":["14738","6280"]}
```

Выводит список с помощью autocomplete (https://goodies.pixabay.com/javascript/auto-complete/auto-complete.js) вида:

```
<div class="autocomplete-suggestions " style="display: none; left: 66px; top: 91px; width: 700px;">
<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-link="/?title=TitleOneRu / TitleOneEn"><a href="?title=TitleOneRu / TitleOneEn">TitleOneRu / TitleOneEn</a></div>
<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-link="/?title=TitleTwoRu / TitleTwoEn"><a href="?title=TitleTwoRu / TitleTwoEn">TitleTwoRu / TitleTwoEn</a></div>
</div>
```

Что нужно сделать, чтобы вывести вышеуказанный список из JSON вида:

```
[{"title_ru":"TitleOneRu","title_en":"TitleOneEn","id":14738,"url":"sil-TitleOne.html"},{"title_ru":"TitleTwoRu","title_en":"TitleTwoEn","id":6280,"url":"sil-TitleTwo.html"}]
```

Вообще в этом не силен, замучался уже(

Comment: Хотите помощи, дайте код нормально, а не кусками. Где вызов функции renderItem которая рендерит список ? Где функция suggest ? Ведь насколько я понимаю именно в ней происходит вызов renderItem.

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал вам сменить сам инструмент. Сам вначале чуть не наступил на грабли. [Select2](https://select2.org) отлично работает и с настройкой вывода данных из удаленных источников и с подачей данных на удаленный сервер.

Comment: Я как-то даже и не думал в этом ключе, сразу решил делать через кроссдоменный запрос и выборку данных с помощью XMLHttpRequest(). На выходе все уже было готово, а потом изменился формат json данных) Боюсь, что буду дольше переключаться на предложенный вами инструмент(

Comment: На самом деле в 99% (утрирую) случаев о правильной отдаче данных должен беспокоиться сервер. Так как у него на много больше методов работы с массивами данных.

Comment: @Dmitry если у вас просто сменился формат выдачи ответа на запрос, так и напишите в своем вопросе.

Comment: Так и есть, раньше JSON приходил в виде {"query":"a","suggestions":{"valu":["TitleOneRu \/ TitleOneEn","TitleTwoRu \/ TitleTwoEn"],"data":["sil-TitleOne.html","sil-TitleTwo.html"],"id":["14738","6280"]}, а сейчас в виде [{"title_ru":"TitleOneRu","title_en":"TitleOneEn","id":14738,"url":"sil-TitleOne.html"},{"title_ru":"TitleTwoRu","title_en":"TitleTwoEn","id":6280,"url":"sil-TitleTwo.html"}] . Поэтому код выборки после JSON.parse(xhrs.responseText) не подходит. Думал, что это понятно, прошу прощения если криво вопрос задал.

Comment: По совету  Vasiliy Rusin сделал через Select2 :) Теперь вопрос не актуален.

Answer (score 1):

функция обработки ответа собирает массив следующих объектов:

```
{
    'title': result.suggestions.valu[i],
    'link': result.data[i],
    'id': result.id[i],
}
```

вам нужно сформировать тот же массив из нового формата данных:

```js
var src = [{"title_ru":"TitleOneRu","title_en":"TitleOneEn","id":14738,"url":"sil-TitleOne.html"},{"title_ru":"TitleTwoRu","title_en":"TitleTwoEn","id":6280,"url":"sil-TitleTwo.html"}];



var suggestions = $.map(src, function(v, idx){
   return {
        'title': v.title_ru + '/' + v.title_en,
        'link': v.url,
        'id': v.id,
    } 
});

console.log(suggestions);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Так что ваша функция становится примерно следующей:

```
source: function(term, suggest) {
    xhrs.open('GET', '/autocomplete.php?name=' + term, false);
    xhrs.onload = function() {

        if (xhrs.status != 200 || xhrs.responseText.length == "") {
            return
        }
        result = JSON.parse(xhrs.responseText)

        var suggestions = $.map(result, function(v, idx){
               if (/sil\-/i.test(v.url) == false) {
                   return null;
               }

               return {
                   'title': v.title_ru + '/' + v.title_en,
                   'link': v.url,
                   'id': v.id,
                 } 
           });

        suggest(suggestions)
    }
    xhrs.send(null);
    alert( xhrs.send(null) );
},
```

ну и раз уж мы пишем на jquery, то давайте модифицируем код в нормальный вид

```
source: function(term, suggest) {
    $.get('autocomplete.php?name=' + term, function(result){

        var suggestions = $.map(result, function(v, idx){
               if (/sil\-/i.test(v.url) == false) {
                   return null;
               }

               return {
                   'title': v.title_ru + '/' + v.title_en,
                   'link': v.url,
                   'id': v.id,
                 } 
           });

        suggest(suggestions);
    });
},
```

Comment: Не помогло или у меня уже окончательный затуп) Добавил образец на GitHub  https://korpatov.github.io/jsonp/, https://github.com/Korpatov/jsonp. Сейчас там данные в форму поиска подгружаются из  autocomplete.json, а надо, чтобы точно также подгружались из autocomplete2.json.